# Python log lines not persisted

Tags: python, logging, gerrit, githooks

I have this very simple snippet of a python script inside a gerrit hook (comment-added)

```
if *condition*:
    message = "Shortened for simplicity"

    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', filename='/home/gerrit/logs/log_approvals.log', level=logging.INFO, filemode='w')
    logging.info(message)
```

My problem is that every time something is written to log_approvals.log, I always see 1 line (the last logged message), so that means that the modifications to the file are not persisted and I don't know why.

Sample output:

```
23/07/2018 08:32:56 AM Shortened for simplicity
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `filemode='a'` instead of `w`. With `a` you append the new lines in the log, with `w` you overwrite the line